# Is this generalized version of plethysm Schur positive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions

**Question:** Suppose that $f(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n)$ is a polynomial with nonnegative integer coefficients. For each permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, let $f_{\sigma}$ denote $f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)})$. Furthermore, suppose that the symmetric function $\sum_{\sigma}f_{\sigma}$ is Schur positive. If we evaluate a Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda}$ at the (multi)set $\{f_{\sigma}\}_{\sigma\in S_n}$ do we get a Schur positive polynomial?

**Motivation:** Billey, Rhoades, and Tewari introduce Chern plethysm as a way to prove Schur positivity of certain polynomials in ["Boolean product polynomials, Schur positivity, and Chern plethysm"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.11165). The operation in the question above is a naive attempt at finding a common generalization of this Chern plethysm and classical plethysm.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to study multisets $(f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_N)$ of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ which are invariant (as a multiset) under $S_n$ action and such that $s_{\lambda}(f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_N)$ is Schur-positive for all $\lambda$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this isn't true. Take $f = x^3+xy^2$, so that $f_{(12)} = y^3+x^2 y$. Then
$$f+f_{(12)} = x^3+x^2 y + x y^2 + y^3=s_3$$
which is Schur positive. But
$$h_2(x^3+xy^2, y^3+x^2 y) = x^6 + x^5 y + 3 x^4 y^2 + 2 x^3 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^4 + x y^5 + y^6$$
$$= s_6+2s_{42}-s_{33}.$$
Actually, simpler:
$$e_2(x^3+xy^2, y^3+x^2 y) = x^5 y + 2 x^3 y^3 + x y^5 = s_{51} - s_{42} + 2 s_{33}.$$